# Ubuntu give server user access to Samba AD Shares

Tags: backup, rsync, ubuntu-15.04

I have an Ubuntu 15.04 Server set up as a AD controller.  The server also has shares for which I have assigned the proper permissions for our staff.  My problem is that I need to backup the shares using rsync on the server but the server user (svradmin) (not being a part of the AD domain) does have SUDO rights but not access to the shares.  How do I get around this?  I am not sure how to give the server user access to backup the shares.

Answer (score 0):

Needed to run rsync under sudo.  Rookie mistake.